# run e edited dont rededit its danger

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, visual-studio, c#-4.0

The first If yuuyworked but other Wwork i don't really know why. also ELSE ll, llseems like when i ydays it yfunction with me.

```
string today = "999/9";
  if (today == DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy"))
    Application.Run((Form) new Program.());
```

so if u still don't understand what i need is, i need the application form to run after a specefic date like above 13/03/2022 so after todays date which is 13/03/2022 has passed and 14/03/2022 has passed ( because i added 1 day ) and 15/03 ( because i added 2 day ) has passed then anything else run the ( else ) statement. i test by changing my pc date and time by days FIRST IF statement worked and ELSE statement worked. but the added days one dosent work. any alternative way?

Comment: Looks like you need your second and third `if` to be `else if`.

Comment: What is the actual goal? Typically, running a program at some date is something for windows task scheduler. For doing something inside a running program at a specific date time you would use a *timer*.

Comment: Please don't make more work for other people by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA 4.0 license](//creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/), for Stack Exchange to distribute that content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By Stack Exchange policy, the non-vandalized version of the post is the one which is distributed. Thus, any vandalism will be reverted. If you want to know more about deleting a post please see: [How does deleting work?](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
string today = "13/03/2022";
  if (today == DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy"))
    Application.Run((Form) new Program.Notification.NotificationForm());
  else if (today == DateTime.Now.AddDays(1).ToString("dd/MM/yyyy"))
    Application.Run((Form) new Program.Notification.NotificationForm());
  else if (today == DateTime.Now.AddDays(2).ToString("dd/MM/yyyy"))
    Application.Run((Form) new Program.Notification.NotificationForm());
  else
    Application.Run((Form) new Program.Notif2.NotificationForm());
```

From your post, I think the `if` setences should be constructed like above.

As for the adding days testing, since you defined `today` as `13/03/2022`, you'll need to set pc time to

- `12/03/2022` to test +1day
- `11/03/2022` to test +2day.

Your variables might need to change names, because `DateTime.Now` is the real date of today (in your system), while `today`, the string variable, is set to be a certain date, which is confusing.

Comment: damnn omg i thought all this time is by adding 1 to add days it should add it to the next day. but it added it by minus. thanks for clearing that out to me.. now i need to put the number in negative -1, -2

Comment: @Mariejose If it works, you could click '✔' to mark it as an answer to change its status to Answered. It will also help others to solve a similar issue. See also [stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote](https://stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote)

Answer (score 1):

Change the comparrison type and reduce the if statements to if/else

```
DateTime today = new DateTime(2022, 03, 13);
        
if (today >= DateTime.Today && today <= DateTime.Today.AddDays(2))              
    Application.Run((Form)new Program.Notification.NotificationForm());
else
    Application.Run((Form)new Program.Notif2.NotificationForm());
```